# No event when the mouse is over a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I add the items from a XML file to a listbox. I whant to write a description of the item in a textblock, when the moues is over a listboxitem.
Here is my XAML cod:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxItemCollection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="10,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="lbi_MouseEnter"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

C# code:

```
private void lbi_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;            
    textBlockDescription.Text = item.Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it works fine (I put a breakpoint in the event handler and it gets it). Do you have any elements in the listbox? Your example code doesn't show any elements being loaded.

Comment: I read the elements from XML file. I've resolved it. I had something else problem. But thanks for the reply.